# Mono: "The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable"

Tags: linux, vb.net, mono

When I try to run my VB.NET application on Debian 6 x86 I get this error:

```
WARNING **: The class System.Collections.Generic.List`1 could not be loaded, used in mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

        mono() [0x80d5b19]
        mono() [0x810f7ab]
        [0xb774f600]
        mono() [0x80620b8]
        mono() [0x80637bf]
        mono() [0x80645c8]
        mono(mono_runtime_invoke+0x40) [0x81cbab0]
        mono(mono_runtime_exec_main+0xde) [0x81cf55e]
        mono(mono_runtime_run_main+0x112) [0x81cf862]
        mono(mono_main+0x15ec) [0x80b3bdc]
        mono() [0x805b675]
        /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6) [0xb74fdc96]
        mono() [0x805b5b1]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

How can I fix this? It doesn't look like my application is causing it, I was able to run the application on another machine with another distro.

Comment: Have you installed `mono-complete`? https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mono-complete

Comment: Yes, I have installed mono-complete, mono-runtime, and mono-vbnc.

Comment: You might run `mono --version` at terminal and compare the two machines' Mono version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because apt-get was installing older versions of mono. However, Ubuntu 12.10 seems to install a newer version.